# Gray bar visible on iPhoneXS throughout app

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

[Header image with gray bar on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6Tgr.jpg)

I am converting our app to fit correctly on newer iOS devices. We are using xib files for the UI. I added a launch screen storyboard to start off the new formatting. I noticed a gray bar across the top of every screen. It is not part of the view controller and I've tried removing the status bar but that only makes the text and icons disappear. I don't think it's the navigation bar either since we have that hidden as well. I have checked the Safe Area Layouts.

Any ideas on what this is and how I can remove it to extend my view all the way to the top? The blue in the image is the color I currently set the background of my view controller and we have a custom header view below that.

Comment: Run `View Hierarchy Debugger` in Xcode, it will show you where this view is located in view hierarchy and where does it come from.

Comment: Thank you. I'd never had to use that before. I was able to see there was a discrepancy in the spacing of the navigationController from a previous developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the View Hierarchy, as suggested, I was able to see the view behind my main view. I inspected the code for that initial view and found the previous developers had offset the Navigation Controller by 20. That is what created the bar on all the views. I have adjusted to remove the offset and it looks perfect now.